# How to Overload a function for 2 generic types in a class

Tags: java

I created a class with 2 generic types (T and K).

```
public class Categorized3DArrayList<T,K>
```

And I decide to create an overloaded function for these 2 generic types

```
private T[] assignValue(T[] value,int i, int counter, int size)
{   
    T[] target = (T[]) new Object[size];
    if(counter > size)
        return null;
    for(int j = i ;j < counter; j++)
    {
        if(value[i] == null)
         return null;
        target[j] = value[j];
    }
    return target;
}    

private K[] assignValue(K[] value,int i, int counter, int size)
{   
    K[] target = (K[]) new Object[size];
    if(counter > size)
        return null;
    for(int j = i ;j < counter; j++)
    {
        if(value[i] == null)
         return null;
        target[j] = value[j];
    }
    return target;
}
```

Hence, this error pops out.

```
Erasure of method assignValue(K[], int, int, int) is the same as another method in type Categorized3DArrayList<T,K>
```

So, I take away the overloaded function of K[],
then I am able to do like this

```
T[] tempArr = assignValue(array[first][second], 0, currentLength, currentLength);
```

But I cannot do like this

```
K[] temp_key2 = assignValue(key2[first], 0, key2Length, key2Length);'
```

This message pops out

```
The method assignValue(T[], int, int, int) in the type Categorized3DArrayList<T,K> is not applicable for the arguments (K[], int, int, int)
```

Can I know what is happening in this situation?

Comment: The code is both same, use one method, and the class type

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to have overloaded functions which use generic types for their arguments because of the type erasure.

It should work if additional type information is provided [as shown here](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk0uiHGGw).

However, the example below shows how the same function may be used for different generic types *without explicit type information*.  It is also recommended to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` for `assignValue`.

[Online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk6GiBMGP)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main<K, V>
{
    public <K, V> void foo(K[] arrK, V[] arrV) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrK));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrV));
        K[] resK = assignValue(arrK, 0, arrK.length/2, arrK.length/2);
        V[] resV = assignValue(arrV, 0, arrV.length/2, arrV.length/2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resK));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resV));
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T[] assignValue(T[] value, int i, int counter, int size) {
        if(counter > size) {
            return null;
        }
        T[] target = (T[]) new Object[size];
    
        for(int j = i; j < counter; j++) {
            if(value[i] == null) {
                return null;
            }
            target[j] = value[j];
        }
        return target;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main<Integer, String> mm = new Main<>();
        mm.foo(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
               new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[a, b, c, d]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[a, b]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: it's working, thanks. btw what's the purpose of <T> between to public and T[] for the assignValue function

Comment: `<T>` before the return type of a method/function indicates that this method/function is [_generic_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).  I also updated the answer to get rid of mentioning explicit class types.